# Como preencher um inputText com base em outro inputText?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Sou iniciante em JSF, PrimeFaces. Tenho um formulário e gostaria que quando um campo recebesse um determinado valor, outro campo retornasse uma informação do Banco de Dados. Exemplo:

No campo `txRecebida`, eu preencho com `1001`, automaticamente no campo `txRecebidaNome` aparece o nome dessa conta.

Segue a minha view:

```html
<p:fieldset legend="Lançamento Padrão">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="painel" layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="form-group col-lg-6 col-xl-6"  
         layout="block">
            <p:outputLabel for="txRecebida" value="Taxas Recebidas à Conta" />
            <p:inputText class="form-control col-4" id="txRecebida"
         label="Taxas Recebidas à Conta"
          value="#{EmpresaMb.planoTaxaRecebida}" />
            <p:inputText class="form-control col-8" id="txRecebidaNome"
        label="txRecebidaNome" disabled="true" />
        </h:panelGroup>
</p:fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz algo parecido com o que você precisa, de uma olhada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Insiro um código para realizar a busca por um veículo que está registrado no Banco de Dados, afim de que me retorne a velocidade do mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se houver registro, vou atualizar o segundo campo de acordo com meu parâmetro de retorno que no caso é a **velocidade**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não haja dados, nenhum veículo será encontrado.

**Segue trecho da minha página que está parecida com a sua:**

```
 <p:fieldset legend="Velocidade de um veículo" style="width:45%; margin-top:15%; margin-left:22%;">

                    <br />
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="painel" layout="block">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="form-group col-lg-6 col-xl-6"
                            layout="block">
                            <p:outputLabel for="txtCodigo" value="Código:"  style="margin-left:4.5%"/>
                            <p:inputText class="form-control col-4" id="txtCodigo"                                
                                value="#{vehicle.id}" style="margin-left:0.4%">
                                 <p:ajax event="keyup" update="txtSpeedRecebido" listener="#{vehicle.actionCarregarCodigo}"/>
                                </p:inputText>                                    
                            <p:outputLabel for="txtSpeedRecebido" value="Velocidade:" style="margin-left:2%;"/>                             
                            <p:inputText class="form-control col-8" id="txtSpeedRecebido" style="margin-left:0.4%"
                                value="#{vehicle.speed}" disabled="true" />  

                                <br />
                                <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true"
                                  autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />                                   
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <br /> 

                        </p:fieldset>


                <p:commandButton value="Reset" id="reset"
                style="margin-left:22%; margin-top:2%;"
                action="#{vehicle.reset}"
                process="@this" update="txtCodigo, txtSpeedRecebido">
                <p:resetInput
                    target="txtCodigo, txtSpeedRecebido" />
                </p:commandButton>
```

Agora o segredo revelado:

```
<p:ajax event="keyup" update="txtSpeedRecebido" listener="#{vehicle.actionCarregarCodigo}"/>
```

Vamos usar o Ajax do Primefaces que está relacionado no primeiro input.
Agora vamos olhar como está distribuída a minha ManagedBean:

```
public String getSpeedById() {

        String speed = null;

        try {           

        TesteDAO dao = new TesteDAO();

        int cod = Integer.parseInt(id);

        speed = dao.pesquisa(cod);  

        if(speed == null)   
             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Warning:", " Nenhum veículo encontrado."));

        else  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info:", " Velocidade encontrada."));


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return speed;
    }
```

O método acima é o que vou realizar a busca no Banco de Dados.

```
public void actionCarregarCodigo(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {

        this.speed = this.getSpeedById();           
    }
```

Acima é o método onde vai realizar a busca de forma automática para mim.
Repare que estou referenciando a variável **speed** para receber o resultado e assim exibir no segundo campo.

**AjaxBehaviorEvent** é uma classe que representa o comportamento do componente específico para Ajax.

como descrito em:

[AjaxBehaviorEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/AjaxBehaviorEvent.html)

```
public void reset() {

        speed = null;
        id = null;

    }
```

Acima é um método apenas para limpar dados do **form**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito origado Well Silva, segui seu exemplo adaptando pro que precisava e consegui chegar ao resultado!

Comment: De nada Ewerton, precisar estamos ai no forúm. Tive um problema parecido para atualizar um checkBox.